# Thumbnail images - Click to load image details

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to display like 9 thumbnail (arranged in 3x3) images in a View Controller.
Then when I touched on one of the thumbnail images, it loads another View Controller,
to display the details of this specific image, like date taken, description of the photo.

I have checked out Three20 project, but im not sure if this is the only way to go?
Are there other ways to do this without using the Three20 project?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do that.
the simplest ways I can think of are:

1. create  a view that holds 9 UIImages and add a gesture recognizer to the views, create a view to hold the deatils and call it each time a view is clicked.
2. create 9 buttons and set the images to the buttons, reate a view to hold the deatils and call it each time a button is clicked.

pretty strait forward.

good luck
shani

Comment: Thanks Shani! I will take your suggestions and give it a try! :)